# How do you create a reusable Vue component with d3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

I'm trying to create a `Chart.vue` component based on D3. I need to be able to add multiple instances to a single page and keep each one separate.

I've tried to assign an ID generated with `uuid` to the div wrapping my component in the template:

```
<template>
  <div :id=this.id>
    <svg></svg>
  </div>
</template>
```

The ID is created when the component is created.

```
<script>
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

export default {
  ...
  created () {
    this.id = uuidv4()
  }, 
  ...
```

The chart is re-rendered when there is an update to the data passed in as `props` from the parent `App.vue`. To select the "correct" `<svg>` element that is owned by a particular instance of `Chart` I use the unique `this.id` in my `renderChart` method:

```
  methods: {
    renderChart(chart_data) {
      const svg_width = 1000;
      const svg_height = 600;
  
      const svg = d3
        .select("#" + this.id)
        .select("svg")
        .attr("width", svg_width)
        .attr("height", svg_height);
      ...
```

Proceeding to add all the axes, data, etc.

If I add two such components to my `App.vue` template:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <form action="#" @submit.prevent="getIssues">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="owner/repo Name"
          v-model="repository"
          class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5"
        >
      </div>
    </form>
    <Chart :issues="issues" />
    <Chart :issues="issues" />
  </div>
</template>
```

I see that they are added to the DOM with some `uuid` that's been created. When the data is updated and the `renderChart` function executes, both components get a copy of the `"issues"` data, but I only see one chart being created.

I'm quite novice with JavaScript, Vue and D3, so perhaps going about this the wrong way, but it seems like this should work?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I seem to have found a solution, although I don't fully understand it, and I'm not sure why the initial approach didn't work (note: original approach did seem to work sometimes, but the behaviour was unpredictable).

To solve, I pass a unique ID to the component from the parent template as a prop and add it as the Chart component `<div>` id.

In `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <form action="#" @submit.prevent="getIssues">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="owner/repo Name"
          v-model="repository"
          class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5"
        >
      </div>
    </form>
    <Chart id="chart1" :issues="issues" />
    <Chart id="chart2" :issues="issues" />        
  </div>
</template>
```

Now I need to add `id` in the `props` of the `Chart.vue` and set a variable in the `data()` section.

```
<template>
  <div :id=chart_id>
    <svg></svg>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as d3 from "d3";

export default {
  name: 'Chart',
  props: ["issues", "id"],
  
  data() {
    return {
      chart: null,
      chart_id: this.id
    };
  },
  ...
```

I'm not sure why the uuid approach didn't work, but this seems more robust.

Comment: Could be because the html id should start with a letter? Could also check if the id generated by uuidv4 is unique in the first place.

Comment: @steven You're correct. The html id must start with a letter, often the uuid begins with a number. You can remedy this by prepending a letter to each uuid: `this.id = 'aa' + uuidv4();`.

I think in my use case, it's actually better to pass a unique ID from the parent, so I can keep track of individual components there, but I may find a use for this in the future.