# D3 working properly only in first instance of Vue 3 component

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm working on Vue 3 app where I would like to use multiple instances of one component. Each component should have its instance of D3 for displaying various SVG images. In my case D3 works as intended only on first instance of Vue component.

Dots are random generated by D3. I can see when inspecting elements that none of dots has been appended in second instance of component. Screenshot of the problem may be found [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i7Mk.png)

My component with D3 looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="fill-100">
    <svg ref="svgRef" width="400" height=667>
      <g></g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import {ref, onMounted} from "@vue/runtime-core";
import {select, zoom} from "d3";

export default {
  name: "SldSvgD3",
  props: ["id"],
  setup() {
    const svgRef = ref(null);

    onMounted(() =>{
      const svg = select(svgRef.value);
      svg.append("svg")


      let data = [], width = 400, height = 667, numPoints = 100;

      let zoom3 = zoom()
        .on('zoom', handleZoom);

      function handleZoom(e) {
          select('svg g')
          .attr('transform', e.transform);
      }

      function initZoom() {
        select('svg')
          .call(zoom3);
      }

      function updateData() {
        data = [];
        for(let i=0; i<numPoints; i++) {
          data.push({
            id: i,
            x: Math.random() * width,
            y: Math.random() * height
          });
        }
      }

      function update() {
        select('svg g')
          .selectAll('circle')
          .data(data)
          .join('circle')
          .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
          .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
          .attr('r', 3);
      }

      initZoom();
      updateData();
      update();

    });

    return {svgRef}
  }
}

</script>


<style lang="scss">
  .fill-100{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Implementation of D3 zoom and pan taken from [this site](https://www.d3indepth.com/zoom-and-pan/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I didn't know is that scope of `d3.select()` call is global for the whole app. Solution in my case was just creating unique *id* for root **div** and selecting this **div** before any manipulation.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63185955/how-do-you-create-a-reusable-vue-component-with-d3) was very helpful to me.

Complete code:

```
<template>
  <div class="fill-100" :id="'sld_div'+this.id">
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import {ref, onMounted} from "@vue/runtime-core";
import * as d3 from "d3";

export default {
  name: "SldSvgD3",
  props: ["id"],
  setup(props) {
    const svgRef = ref(null);
    const svg_width = 400;
    const svg_height = 667;

    onMounted(() =>{

        const svg = d3
          .select("#sld_div"+props.id)
        svg.append("svg")
          .attr("id","sld_root"+props.id)
          .attr("width", svg_width)
          .attr("height", svg_height)
        .append("g")
          .attr("id","sld_root_g"+props.id)

      let data = [], width = 600, height = 400, numPoints = 100;

      let zoom = d3.zoom()
        .on('zoom', handleZoom);

      function handleZoom(e) {
        d3.select("#sld_div"+props.id)
          .select('svg g')
          .attr('transform', e.transform);
      }

      function initZoom() {
        d3.select("#sld_div"+props.id)
          .select('svg')
          .call(zoom);
      }

      function updateData() {
        data = [];
        for(let i=0; i<numPoints; i++) {
          data.push({
            id: i,
            x: Math.random() * width,
            y: Math.random() * height
          });
        }
      }

      function update() {
        d3.select("#sld_div"+props.id)
          .select('svg g')
          .selectAll('circle')
          .data(data)
          .join('circle')
          .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
          .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
          .attr('r', 3);
      }

      initZoom();
      updateData();
      update();

    });

    return {svgRef}
  }
}

</script>


<style lang="scss">
  .fill-100{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for sharing the solution it was really helpful